# How to call custom attribute value from back-end code in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php, backend

I have create a custom attribute call manufacturer_email from the backend and assign the values for the products.

The main reason for this is i need to fire an email to its manufacturer when an customer place a order through the web site. I found the observe for this and also how to  fire the email.

**The problem is the custom attribute returns an empty result without the email address.**
can anyone tell me how to get the value for this attribute???

**Backend Code**

```
public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{        
  $order = $observer->getOrder();

  $email_stacks = array();
  foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
  {
     // only add simple products to email, not a configurable product for example
     if ($item->getData('product_type')!=Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
        continue;

     $manufacturer = $item->getData('manufacturer_email');
     $sku = $item->getData('sku');
     Mage::log(" {$manufacturer} and {$sku} updated", null, 'manufacturer-email.log');
```

**Result**

```
2014-09-08T12:35:32+00:00 DEBUG (7):   and SKU5001 updated
```

**Attribute and inputs**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through so many codes i found ANSWER

```
$manufacturer= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getData('manufacturer_email');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `$item->getData('manufacturer_email');`

Do:  $item->getProduct()->getData('manufacturer_email');

The reason for this is that when you add a product to cart only some of it's attributes are transferred to the quote item object, sku being one of them. By default Magento behavior, custom attributes like manufacturer_email would not be added to the quote item object/table. So you need to retrieve the value from the product object.

Comment: Be careful, I doubt that data will get pulled across into the item product model.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Still no luck :(

$manufacturer = $item->getProduct()->getData('manufacturer_email');
         $sku = $item->getData('sku');
         Mage::log(" {$manufacturer} and {$sku} updated", null, 'manufacturer-email.log');

2014-09-08T12:35:32+00:00 DEBUG (7):   and SKU5001 updated
2014-09-08T12:55:18+00:00 DEBUG (7):   and SKU5001 updated

Comment: You should log: $item->getProduct()->getData() and see it's content. Your custom attribute should be there.

Comment: 2014-09-08T12:58:31+00:00 DEBUG (7):  Array and SKU5001 updated

Comment: @ParasSood see my reply below

Comment: @NirangaJayakody the data you're trying to retrieve isn't set within the $item model, thus it's returning null/empty. See my response of how to get the data properly into the item model.

Comment: @Dave Well Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item has the function getProduct() which I am calling on order item. This returns the product for the order item from which I am trying to fetch the attribute value.

Comment: @ParasSood my mistake, I skimmed the question to quickly! I don't think his attribute is being pulled across. The method implements basic caching in the form of $this->getData('product');